# Check if host is in Consul in maintenance mode or not

Tags: shell, consul

I am writing a check for our monitoring if a given host is in maintenance mode in Consul (0.8.5) or not. On the command line is is quite simple as I can run `consul maint` and get a appropriate output. Via REST I can set the maintenance mode, but it seems not to be possible to retrieve it.

How can I check this in a shell script in a safe manner without parsing the multiline output of Consul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a node is in maintenance via `http://localhost:8500/v1/health/node/name_of_node`. If the node is in maintenance mode, then the output will contain an entry with the check ID `_node_maintenance`.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8500/v1/health/node/name_of_node
[
  {
    "ModifyIndex": 270813,
    "CreateIndex": 270813,
    "ServiceTags": [],
    "Node": "name_of_node",
    "CheckID": "_node_maintenance",
    "Name": "Node Maintenance Mode",
    "Status": "critical",
    "Notes": "Maintenance mode is enabled for this node, but no reason was provided. This is a default message.",
    "Output": "",
    "ServiceID": "",
    "ServiceName": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options to get list of servers that are in maintenance:

using curl and jq:

```
curl http://localhost:8500/v1/health/service/<serviceName>\?dc\=<dcKey> | jq '.[].Checks[] | select(.CheckID == "_node_maintenance")'
```

using groovy (returns list of servers names):

```
List<String> getServersInMaintenance(String serviceName, String dc) {
    List<String> serversList = []
    def uri = "/v1/health/service/${serviceName}"

    //* this is a RestClient that takes uri, query and content type
    def response = this.get(uri,
            [dc: dc, passing: false],
            ContentType.JSON
    )

    List allChecks = response.data.Checks
    for (server in allChecks) {
        for(check in server) {
            if (check.Name.contains("Maint") && check.Status.equals("critical")) {
                serversList += "${check.Node}"
            }
        }
    }

    return serversList
}
```